# Cannot run raw Query in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I need to get total count to show in my page.

I can run this & loop through & get the total number

```
DB::table('table1')
    ->select((DB::raw('MAX(score)')))
    ->where('status', 1)
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->get();
```

But this query would give me the count in just a single query & I don't need run any extra loop to get the total.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM (
  SELECT MAX( score ) FROM table1
  WHERE status =1
  GROUP BY user_id
) AS totalCounter
```

How am I suppose to run this RAW query in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by other contributors;-

```
DB::select('SQL QUERY GOES HERE WITH PARAMETERS ?, ?', array('parameter 1', 'parameter 2'));
```

The code above should permit raw sql.

However,

```
DB::table('table1')
    ->select((DB::raw('MAX(score)')))
    ->where('status','=', 1)
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->count();
```

Should achieve the same effect for the task you seek it for, and is more in tune with laravels philosophy.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
DB::statement( 'Your Query' );
```

or

```
DB::select( 'Your Query' );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SQL QUERY CODE HERE"))
```

Both raw and select are require!

Please see for more info:
[Laravel 4: how to run a raw SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687993/laravel-4-how-to-run-a-raw-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM table_Name WHERE col = :somevariable"), array(
   'somevariable' => $someVariable,
 ));
```