# Laravel 4 cannot run whole RAW queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to use the DB class of laravel to execute a mysql query but none of the functions provided by Laravel are working.

None of those is working: DB::statment() / DB::select() / DB::raw() / DB::update() / DB::select(DB::raw())

Here is the code I would like to query:

```
DROP TABLE users;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `u_username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `u_email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `u_regdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `u_birthday` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `u_lastlogin` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `u_logcout` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `u_level` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `u_language` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `u_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `u_gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO users VALUES("1","admin","admin@example.com","$2y$08$9sBJh7iyF9Yr6xvsieNmBOsotGPBkZFydVjb/Yk5Fzh4IGBVo7Je6","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00","0","0","9","0","0","0");
INSERT INTO users VALUES("2","moderator","mod@example.com","$2y$08$15/tIKPM/8gATSzkmey5tuAA/PL4lJeFq7liTETyz0h1dkOotwp3G","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00","0","0","0","0","0","0");
INSERT INTO users VALUES("3","helper","help@example.com","$2y$08$nTtZU9/UBeRLbYJRO/XwCe2D/B57ofx2bCN8vGEiHkqO.bPra0WT6","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00","0","0","0","0","0","0");
INSERT INTO users VALUES("4","dude12","dude@example.com","$2y$08$y0JweKtWxJFRF7Ko8q0zkODY.EWEKJ.CR1dDco6aCJh8ssKdzQ6RC","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00","0","0","0","0","0","0");
INSERT INTO users VALUES("5","girl1","girl@example.com","$2y$08$UKjJzxDuYW7upqeLsm1VOOo2jUoqMaai0/1jFxvLDzC6eWjin3yOe","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00","0","0","0","0","0","0");
```

I have looked and tried methods from those two topics too but nothing is working:

[cannot-run-raw-query-in-laravel-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601409/cannot-run-raw-query-in-laravel-4)

[laravel-4-how-to-run-a-raw-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687993/laravel-4-how-to-run-a-raw-sql?lq=1)

Error returned when executing with "DB::select( DB::raw($query) )" or DB::statement :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `users` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `u_use' at line 3 (SQL: DROP TABLE users; CREATE TABLE `users` ( `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `u_username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `u_email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `u_regdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `u_birthday` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00', `u_lastlogin` int(11) NOT NULL, `u_logcout` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `u_level` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `u_language` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `u_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', `u_gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci; INSERT INTO users VALUES("1","admin","admin@example.com","$2y$08$9sBJh7iyF9Yr6xvsieNmBOsotGPBkZFydVjb/Yk5Fzh4IGBVo7Je6","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00","0","0","9","0","0","0"); INSERT INTO users VALUES("2","moderator","mod@example.com","$2y$08$15/tIKPM/8gATSzkmey5tuAA/PL4lJeFq7liTETyz0h1dkOotwp3G","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00","0","0","0","0","0","0"); INSERT INTO users VALUES("3","helper","help@example.com","$2y$08$nTtZU9/UBeRLbYJRO/XwCe2D/B57ofx2bCN8vGEiHkqO.bPra0WT6","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00","0","0","0","0","0","0"); INSERT INTO users VALUES("4","dude12","dude@example.com","$2y$08$y0JweKtWxJFRF7Ko8q0zkODY.EWEKJ.CR1dDco6aCJh8ssKdzQ6RC","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00","0","0","0","0","0","0"); INSERT INTO users VALUES("5","girl1","girl@example.com","$2y$08$UKjJzxDuYW7upqeLsm1VOOo2jUoqMaai0/1jFxvLDzC6eWjin3yOe","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00","0","0","0","0","0","0"); ) (Bindings: array ( ))
```

Comment: can you show the error that it is giving while excuting the query with DB class?

Comment: added the error returned to the main question. when i try executing the query with phpmyadmin, it works perfectly

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Executing SQL Code just like the one I provided in the question can be executed using

```
DB::unprepared( $code );
```

I hope this helps the people with the same issue i had :D

[Answer found while looking through laravel issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/54)

Comment: @OmerM. How are you incorporating DB class in your system. Did you create a Model or called directly in controller?

Comment: @Volatil3 For this project I used the DB class in a PHP Command Class. I wanted to create an artisan command which i could use to export and import my db. You can use the DB Class anywhere in your whole Project. In your controller or your model.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the users table from database then try this and let me know whether it works or not:

```
DB::insert('CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `u_username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `u_email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `u_regdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `u_birthday` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `u_lastlogin` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `u_logcout` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `u_level` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `u_language` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `u_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `u_gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci');

//and so on for all the other queries.
```

Comment: DB::query does not exist in laravel 4, so I used DB::insert and it worked.
I guess executing multiple queries at the same time is not possible but executing them one by one is working

Comment: yes that is correct you need to execute the query individually and thanks for telling about the DB::query not existing in laravel 4.I will change the answer as such with insert()

Comment: Just found out there is a function for executing raw mysql code: DB::unprepared( $code ); https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/54

Answer (score 2):

What about this code?
I find it pretty usefull to use [migrations & db seeding](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations) - especialy for deployment.

```
Schema::create('users', function($table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('u_username');
    $table->string('u_email');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->datetime('u_regdate');
    $table->date('u_birthday');
    $table->integer('u_lastlogin');
    $table->integer('u_logcout')->default(0);
    $table->tinyinteger('u_level')->default(0);
    $table->tinyinteger('u_language')->default(0);
    $table->tinyinteger('u_status')->default(0);
    $table->tinyinteger('u_gender')->default(0);
});


// Repeat this for other users as well
User::create([
    'u_username' =>     'admin',
    'u_email' =>        'admin@example.com',
    'password' =>       Hash::make('users-password'),
    'u_regdate' =>      date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'u_birthday' =>     '1980-01-01',
    'u_lastlogin' =>    0,
    'u_logcout' =>      0,
    'u_level' =>        9,
    'u_language' =>     0,
    'u_status' =>       0,
    'u_gender' =>       0,
]);
```