# How to get the first record with laravel 4 raw queries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can i get the first record with laravel 4 raw queries.

Something like `DB::select('')->first();` is not working 
neither did `DB::first('')`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687993/laravel-4-how-to-run-a-raw-sql

Comment: @jeewiya i'm asking specifically on how to get the FIRST RECORD like using the first() method like with Eloquent.

Comment: Just added a feature request: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11896

Answer (score 27):

The fact is that DB:select() returns an array, so you have to:

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select * from users'))[0];
```

You also can

```
DB::table('users')->first();
```

Comment: This is what i have right now but i was hoping for an alternative. Thanks anyway

Comment: Giving another option. But, as I said, select will return an array directly, not an object, so there are no methods.

Comment: DB::select(DB::raw('select * from users'))[0]; triggers an undefined offset exception if no records found

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
DB::table('users')->take(1)->get()[0];
```

Comment: This triggers an undefined offset exception if no records found.

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('users')->first(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using eloquent you can do this:

```
 $user = User::take(1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$allmarketers = ProductStock::take(3)->get()[2];
```

Take will return how many rows you want and you use the offset like 2 to pick individual rows