# How to execute raw queries with Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel-5.1

So I have this tiny query to run on my DB and it works fine in MySQL Workbench.
Basically, a SELECT with LEFT JOIN and UNION with LEFT JOIN again.

```
SELECT
    cards.id_card,
    cards.hash_card,
    cards.`table`,
    users.name,
    0 as total,
    cards.card_status,
    cards.created_at
FROM cards
LEFT JOIN users
ON users.id_user = cards.id_user
WHERE hash_card NOT IN ( SELECT orders.hash_card FROM orders )
UNION
SELECT
    cards.id_card,
    orders.hash_card,
    cards.`table`,
    users.name,
    sum(orders.quantity*orders.product_price) as total, 
    cards.card_status, 
    max(orders.created_at) 
FROM menu.orders
LEFT JOIN cards
ON cards.hash_card = orders.hash_card
LEFT JOIN users
ON users.id_user = cards.id_user
GROUP BY hash_card
ORDER BY id_card ASC
```

In tried to translate it to Laravel, with no success.

```
$cards = Card::selectRaw('cards.id_card, cards.hash_card ,cards.table, users.name, 0 as total, cards.card_status, cards.created_at as last_update')
                ->leftJoin('users','users.id_user','=','cards.id_user')
                ->whereNotIn( 'hash_card', Order::select('orders.hash_card')->get() )
                ->union(
                        Order::selectRaw('cards.id_card, orders.hash_card, cards.table, users.name, sum(orders.quantity*orders.product_price) as total, cards.card_status, max(orders.created_at) as last_update')
                        ->leftJoin('cards','cards.hash_card','=','orders.hash_card')
                        ->leftJoin('users','users.id_user','=','cards.id_user')
                )
                ->groupBy('hash_card')
                ->orderBy('cards.id_card','asc')
                ->get();
```

I'm getting the error

> ErrorException in Builder.php line 1249: Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$bindings

How could I execute a completely raw query in Laravel or write the query in the right manner in Laravel?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

I found the solution in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687993/laravel-4-how-to-run-a-raw-sql) and I code this:

```
$cards = DB::select("SELECT
        cards.id_card,
        cards.hash_card,
        cards.`table`,
        users.name,
        0 as total,
        cards.card_status,
        cards.created_at as last_update
    FROM cards
    LEFT JOIN users
    ON users.id_user = cards.id_user
    WHERE hash_card NOT IN ( SELECT orders.hash_card FROM orders )
    UNION
    SELECT
        cards.id_card,
        orders.hash_card,
        cards.`table`,
        users.name,
        sum(orders.quantity*orders.product_price) as total, 
        cards.card_status, 
        max(orders.created_at) last_update 
    FROM menu.orders
    LEFT JOIN cards
    ON cards.hash_card = orders.hash_card
    LEFT JOIN users
    ON users.id_user = cards.id_user
    GROUP BY hash_card
    ORDER BY id_card ASC");
```

Comment: You actually don't even need to nest the DB::Raw call. You can just call DB::select("... your query string...");

Comment: I have a question if  I may. Does using raw sql queries via query builder(with or without DB::raw) in Laravel 5 (5.3 to be exact) is enough to prevent sql injection? I have found some article about it but it's for Laravel 4. I can't find one convincing confirmation.

Comment: by itself, DB::select does not protect against SQL injection. However, by ensuring that all user-provided input has been run through $safe_string = DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($string) you can protect your code.

Comment: You can bind parameters to raw queries to prevent SQL injections... https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries

Comment: It will slow your query it's a bad idea.

Comment: Can we paginate data on this query ?

Comment: I believe you can by appending a "LIMIT" and "OFFSET" in your raw query -> https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/mysql-limit-offset

Comment: Dont forget to bind parameters to avoid SQL injections as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/953833/jabari

Answer (score 55):

```php
    DB::statement("your query")
```

I used it for add index to column in migration

Answer (score 4):

Example from Laravel documentation:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as user_count, status')
    ->where('status', '<>', 1)
    ->groupBy('status')
    ->get();
```

Another example:

```
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->leftjoin('category','category.product_id','=','products.id')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) as nbr', 'products.*')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->get();
```

Another example – we can even perform avg() and count() in the same statement.

```
$salaries = DB::table('salaries')
    ->selectRaw('companies.name as company_name, avg(salary) as avg_salary, count(*) as people_count')
    ->join('companies', 'salaries.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
    ->groupBy('companies.id')
    ->orderByDesc('avg_salary')
    ->get();
```

Credits:
https://blog.quickadminpanel.com/5-ways-to-use-raw-database-queries-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use

```
DB::unprepared()
```

Answer (score -30):

you can run raw query like this way too.

```
DB::table('setting_colleges')->first();
```

Comment: this is not a Raw query method in Laravel , it just get the first row of that table

Comment: This is the bad query. :(