# SQL inner join wrong output from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Students Table:

```
ID | Family_ID | Student_name | F_name
```

Families Table:

```
ID | F_name | Contact_No
```

i want to get all records from students where family_id is repeating.(basically i want to know students Brothers/Sisters records if there is any in student table.

i tried it this way but got wrong output;

```
SELECT students.*
FROM students
INNER JOIN families 
    ON families.id = students.family_id
    ORDER BY families.id ASC
```

[my query result in image: as you can see some ids are showing once others are more then once, but i think all should appear more then once.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGg90.png)

Comment: If they dont exist in the families table and you want them returned you would use a left join.  otherwise give more details on wrong data and provide data examples

Comment: @Brad i want only those rows which exist

Comment: If you can show the input and output sample ?Btw inner join means common records for some same ids in both the tables in your case.

Comment: This query will give you all the students records whose family ID is present in the family table even if their family ID is not repeated in any other record.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja image attached please check

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy solution i want only repeated ids result?

Comment: here is an example of how you can provide you data sample instead of image http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92512f/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see only relevant people you don't need to link it to the families table. You can group the student with family_id. Here is your query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student
WHERE family_id IN (SELECT family_id 
                    FROM students 
                    GROUP BY family_id 
                    HAVING COUNT(1)>1)
ORDER BY family_id
```

Comment: @Alex You are right, thanks for double checking. Every day I surprise myself :)

Comment: Perfect Thankyou @Zeki Gumus

Comment: Group by does all the magic. Even I tried the same but my bad I tried including group by in the students table itself but great you avoid joins for the better. :)

Comment: @Alex can you please tell me Laravel eloquent of this query?

Comment: @iMatti  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049511/how-to-execute-raw-queries-with-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a join on subquery for the family_id that have more that one rows in students

```
SELECT students.*
FROM students
inner join  (
    select students.family_id
    FROM students
    group by students.family_id
    having count(*)>1
) t on t. family_id = students.family_id
```

Comment: Isn't the join unnecessary here both in the query and the subquery?

Comment: why unncessary?  .. a join is equivalent that an IN clause but more performant

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy   . you are welcome  .. the use of inner join on  a subquery is always  preferable  to a IN clause  .. an IN clause is equivalent to severl OR condition  .  INNER JOIN don't need the reiteration over the main table for match the rows

Comment: @scaisEdge why your query is retrieving some single ids?

Comment: @iMatti explain better  .. the query shold retrive the students that have a family with more than one students