# Building a raw query into the Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Could anyone please help me to build the following query into the Laravel Query Builder. I only know how to query into the database using raw query.

```
SELECT ru.external_ref_no AS SID, usd.user_name AS Username, rs.servicecode AS Package, rc.clientdesc as Entity, rc.clientip as NAS_IP,
ROUND((ROUND((SUM(usd.FREE_UPLOAD_OCTETS)/1048576)))/1024,2) AS Upload,
ROUND((ROUND((SUM(usd.FREE_DOWNLOAD_OCTETS)/1048576)))/1024,2) AS Download,
ROUND((ROUND((SUM(usd.FREE_UPLOAD_OCTETS)/1048576)))/1024,2) + ROUND((ROUND((SUM(usd.FREE_DOWNLOAD_OCTETS)/1048576)))/1024,2) AS Total_Usage
FROM user_session_detail usd, radservice rs, radclient rc, radgroup rg, raduser ru 
WHERE ru.username=usd.user_name AND rs.serviceid=usd.service_id AND rg.groupid=usd.group_id 
AND usd.client_id=rc.clientid AND usd.SESSION_START_TIME > '2021-09-30 00.00.01' AND usd.SESSION_START_TIME < '2021-09-30 23.59.59'
GROUP BY usd.user_name
HAVING (ROUND((SUM(usd.FREE_UPLOAD_OCTETS)/1048576)))/1024 + (ROUND((SUM(usd.FREE_DOWNLOAD_OCTETS)/1048576)))/1024 > 15
AND (ROUND((SUM(usd.FREE_UPLOAD_OCTETS)/1048576)))/1024 + (ROUND((SUM(usd.FREE_DOWNLOAD_OCTETS)/1048576)))/1024 < 20;
```

Comment: kindly have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049511/how-to-execute-raw-queries-with-laravel-5-1

Comment: what is alais ```usd``` refer to

Comment: It seems that query is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query is very customized and can not be written by eloquent and query builder so you can run it as a raw SQL like this:

```
$results = DB::select("... your customized SQL query ...");
```

then you can pass the variable `$results` to your blade:

```
return view('reports.secretuserlist',compact('results'));
```

in the blade, you can access the data via the `$results` variable

Comment: Is the following line okay to pass the value to blade? Because i'm getting an error ""UserSessionDetail" Undefined Variable
return view('reports.secretuserlist',compact('$userSessionDetail'));

Comment: @RaceTech your result will be an array and its ok to pass the value to balade like this: view('reports.secretuserlist',compact('results')). note that the argument in compact is not a variable, it is string (without $)

Comment: Without return view, i also tried to get the output using "dd" but still not working. Could you please advice on this and write the output code for me. It would be a great help.