# How to run a classic SQL query in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'am new to Laravel and wish to run this classic SQL query:

```
select skill_question.skill_id from skill_question, skill_result 
  where skill_question.question_id = skill_result.correct_answered_question
```

How should I do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4: how to run a raw SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687993/laravel-4-how-to-run-a-raw-sql)

Comment: Documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DB class to do what you want. example

```
 DB::select(DB::raw('select skill_question.skill_id from skill_question, skill_result where skill_question.question_id = skill_result.correct_answered_question'));
```