# How to get 5km distance surroundings when im giving current latitude and longitude in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this query working fine or not ??
any one help to execute this query, i want 5km surrounding values when i giving curent latittide and longitude

```
SELECT
    id, (
      3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(12.966958) )
      * cos( radians( latitude ) )
      * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(80.1525835) )
      + sin ( radians(12.966958) )
      * sin( radians( latitude ) )
    )
) AS distance
FROM place
HAVING distance < 5 ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: which error did you get .can  you show table structure

Comment: have you tried to use "where" instead of "having" in your query?

Comment: @arul-dass-d the way you have formed the query is not correct. Checkout http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html. I've written an answer to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HAVING` is used only when you want to filter results after an aggregation function - You have to use `WHERE` here.

Also,

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.
>   This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is
>   evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

```
SELECT id, distance FROM(
SELECT
    id, (
      3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(12.966958) )
      * cos( radians( latitude ) )
      * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(80.1525835) )
      + sin ( radians(12.966958) )
      * sin( radians( latitude ) )
    )
) AS distance
FROM place) tmp
WHERE tmp.distance >5
ORDER by distance
```

Comment: "Standard SQL..." - is that a qoute? because it is logically totally wrong.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Check this:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html

Comment: its working...How can i write this in laravel ?? do u have any ideas ??

Comment: @AruldassD You can refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687993/laravel-4-how-to-run-a-raw-sql