# How to convert sql query to db raw in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

Shortly, I want to get the action row of each opportunity with the last date and last time.

This is my action table.

[image]

This is what I want to get result.

[image]

I wrote sql for this algorithm in the below.

```
Select opportunities.id,

           opportunity_actions.id,
           opportunity_actions.hour,
           opportunity_actions.date
                 from opportunities
                    left join opportunity_actions ON opportunity_actions.opportunity_id = opportunities.id  
                    WHERE (

                       date = (
                           SELECT MAX(date)
                           FROM opportunity_actions   AS lookup
                          WHERE lookup.opportunity_id  = opportunity_actions.opportunity_id
                       ) AND
                       hour = (
                           SELECT MAX(hour)
                           FROM opportunity_actions   AS lookup
                          WHERE lookup.opportunity_id  = opportunity_actions.opportunity_id AND date=(SELECT MAX(date)
                           FROM opportunity_actions   AS lookup
                          WHERE lookup.opportunity_id  = opportunity_actions.opportunity_id)
                       )
                        OR opportunity_actions.id IS NULL)
```

Sql is working correctly. But I want to write this algorithm with db raw method in laravel. I wrote the code below. But It is not working. Values appear more than once. Please help me.

```
$data = DB::table('opportunities')
            ->select(
               'opportunities.id',
               'opportunity_actions.hour',
               'opportunity_actions.date',
               'opportunity_actions.id',
               DB::raw('(SELECT MAX(opportunity_actions.date)  FROM opportunity_actions
                WHERE opportunity_actions.opportunity_id =  opportunities.id OR (opportunity_actions.id IS NULL)
               ) as dateMax'),
               DB::raw('(SELECT MAX(opportunity_actions.hour)  FROM opportunity_actions
                WHERE( opportunity_actions.opportunity_id =  opportunities.id
                AND opportunity_actions.date = dateMax  
                OR opportunity_actions.id IS NULL)
               ) as hourMax')
           )
           ->leftJoin('opportunity_actions', 'opportunity_actions.opportunity_id', '=', 'opportunities.id')
           ->get();
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships You can choose to either do belongsTo, belongsTo, or drop one of the relation fields and use a hasOne and a belongs two

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. I want to help for db raw.

Comment: Just do a join?

Comment: I already have tried. It's not working.

Comment: Recreate your sample tables in http://sqlfiddle.com/ and i'll help you.

Comment: There have tables above. Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 4: how to run a raw SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687993/laravel-4-how-to-run-a-raw-sql)

Comment: No, I'm trying to show the closest time and the closest date actions in the table with db raw structure laravel 8.